# Ошибка при отправке файла на сервер Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Отправляю файл на сервер с помощью `Retrofit2`, использую `POST` метод для отправки файла, POST метод принимает два параметра "file" и "shared-with":

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("im-file")
    Call<RequestBody> sendFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                               @Part("shared-with") String sharedWith);
```

метод для отправки файлов на сервер:

```
private void testSendFile(){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + "gallery.png");
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
    Call<RequestBody> call = BaseApi.getInstance().service.sendFile(body, "bob");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RequestBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RequestBody> call, Response<RequestBody> response) {

            Log.e("Response: ", String.valueOf(response));
            Log.e("Response headers in send file: ", String.valueOf(response.headers()));
            Log.e("Response code in send file: ", String.valueOf(response.code()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RequestBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("File send error: ", t);
        }
    });
}
```

Получаю 400 ошибку, `"message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/"`.

Когда тестирую запрос в Postman, то все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что может быть не так?

Comment: А какой URL в Postman?

Comment: Объект `file` нормально инициализируется?

Comment: @post_zeew вроде бы, да

Comment: @MikhailVaysman url в Postman выглядит так api.xxxx.net:8000/im-file

Comment: @Lucky_girl меня смущает, что в ошибке упомянут другой путь /, а не /im-file

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Пример запроса, который указан в описании API, выглядит так: api.xxxx.net:8000/im-file file@~/Desktop/dancing-banana.gif "Authorization:Bearer e35eb23d94ca4cf7aa0811ab104b90d2" shared-with=bob

Comment: @MikhailVaysman я так понимаю, что сервер не видит, что первый параметр называется "file"

Comment: А в лог сервера можно посмотреть?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman  у меня сейчас нету доступа к логам сервера, то что выдает в логах Android Studio:  status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, неправильно задано имя части с файлом. Попробуйте

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

вместо

```
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку: @Part parameters using the MultipartBody.Part must not include a part name in the annotation.

Comment: агга. исправил ответ.

Comment: Если меняю picture на file, то получаю ошибку Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args

Comment: это уже следующая история. в описании запроса в Call<MyResponse> должен быть указан класс, в который парсер разберет ответ сервера. обычный java класс с несколькими полями. а у вас там ResponseBody. парсер пытается создать экземпляр этого класса, прежде чем будет его заполнять, и не может, потому что  ResponseBody предназначен совсем для другого.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало!